# How do you open the shortcut to the ice world?

Tags: spelunky-hd

I've reached the third world (ice world) three times, and I pay the tunnel man every time I get there. But after I log in the next time, the shortcut is still only for the second world (jungle world). Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

> To unlock the shortcut to the Ice Caverns you will have to give the
>   Tunnel Man two bombs the first time you complete the level, two ropes
>   the second, and the third time you have to give him a Shotgun. The
>   shortcut will unlock to the right of the World 2: The Jungle shortcut.

http://www.ign.com/wikis/spelunky/World_3:_Ice_Caverns

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Revelanth from Steam.
Here is his answer:
    "Technically you're helping him to complete the tunnel, not bribing him. He will ask for stuff that he needs three times (bombs, then ropes, and finally money/specific item)."